# Trying to create an .MP4 from .TIF frames, syntax works on MacOS but not Windows 10

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mp4

I currently use FFMPEG to create .GIFs from a set of .TIF frames and now my use case is making me need to instead make an .MP4 video from the same set of .TIF frames.

This syntax works just fine on my Mac:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 4 -i frame_%02d.tif out.mp4
```

But using ffmpeg.exe on Windows and passing the same arguments, I receive an error on the `-framerate` token.  Any ideas as to why?

Thanks in advance.
Randal Stout

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ffmpeg are you using? The command works for me (`ffmpeg version 2021-03-28-git-8b2bde0494-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev`). Type `ffmpeg -version` to see your version.

`-framerate` is an alias for `-r` ([see docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#:%7E:text=%2Dr%5B%3Astream_specifier%5D%20fps%20(input/output%2Cper%2Dstream))), so try using `-r` instead.

Comment: Of all things.  The -version I am using is newer than that.  Yes, with changing to -r instead of -framerate, it works perfectly.  Thank you!!